# Xamarin runtime "plugins" or scripts

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

We are designing a generic Android application using Xamarin Forms. At the same time, we need some texts that the user enters to be treated a bit differently for some of the customers, ie. run them through a custom transformation.

Instead of having to build a different version of our generic app, it would be great if we could define those transformations as an external dependency, as a pluggable "dll" or a text file with a script, maybe something like MoonSharp.

Does anyone have experience with something similar and how to achieve that in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: I'm looking for the same information. I want to be able to add new UI panels with functionality via plugins to mine. Unfortunately searching "xamarin.forms plugins" gives results for pcl libraries. Terrible name confusion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did end up using the MoonSharp framework and the Lua scripting in two different projects, one on Xamarin, and another one on a classic windows service C# application. It was a great tool and gets the job done!